# Error al acceder al panel de administracion de Django

Tags: python, django, anaconda

Tengo un proyecto en *Django* el cual ejecuto en un entorno virtual a través de *Anaconda*.
Al ejecutar
    `python manage.py runserver`

se inicia el servidor y puedo acceder a la pagina correctamente, pero cuando trato de acceder al panel de administración con `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` el servidor cae automáticamente si dar ningún tipo de fallo.

Espero que puedan orientarme con esto.

Un saludo.

Comment: Te da un error al momento de acceder al admin? ya sea en la terminal, o algo?

Comment: No me genera ningún tipo de fallo. Lanzo con runserver el servidor Django, puedo acceder a la pagina de mi proyecto y navegar por ella con normalidad. Al ir a la ruta del admin el navegador da fallo al acceder a la página, y en la terminal solo se ve que se ha parado el servidor, del mismo modo que cuando uno lo para manualmente.

Si necesitas algún dato o que revise algo por favor dímelo.

Un saludo.

Comment: A que te refieres con "del mismo modo que cuando uno lo para manualmente"? Por otra parte no has sobrescrito o alterado las urls del admin o algo así?

Comment: Hola Julio, te comento. Cuando uno inicia el servidor, tu puedes pararlo con Ctrl+C en la terminal (al menos en Windows) . Esto no da ningún mensaje ni nada, solo lo paras. Pues mientras que tengo el servidor activo, funciona todo bien, y te diriges a la ruta del panel de administrador de Django (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin), automáticamente te para el servidor del mismo modo que con Ctrl+C, automáticamente.  Lo único que he hecho antes de que dejara de funcionar fue, crear un super user para acceder a este panel, y desde ese momento dejo de funcionar.

Comment: Vaya que raro, no tengo ni la menor idea de que esta ocasionando esto o porque sucede. A lo mejor tienes una versión de Django inestable o yo que se. Intenta eliminar el proyecto y crea uno nuevo desde cero y a lo mejor se soluciona.

Answer (score 0):

Este error puede ocurrir porque la versión de Django es antigua o no compatible. Puede resolverse subiendo de versión de Django.

Si es en Windows pon el comando:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Y si es en Linux o Mac:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/323032)